# how to fetch data from back-end

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The back-end generated the data API, and how to fetch data on the front end
ps： I use react

URL:  http://localhost:8080/api/barrages

#### when request the above url, the browser displays as follows.

```
{
    "content": [
        {
            "key": 12344443434545435,
            "text": "绿色走一波",
            "time": 500,
            "fontFamily": null,
            "fontsize": null,
            "color": "#0f0",
            "video_id": null,
            "creationDateTime": "2019-04-08T13:59:51Z"
        }
    ],
    "page": 0,
    "size": 30,
    "totalElements": 1,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "last": true
}
```

#### Front-end:  get data

```
fetch("/api/barrages", { method: 'GET' })
    .then(function (res) {
        res.json()
           .then(function (barrage) {
          console.log(barrage);
        }
        )
      })
```

I want to get the data of content

Comment: when execute  ' console.log(barrage)'  , the result may be '  {
            "key": 12344443434545435,
            "text": "绿色走一波",
            "time": 500,
            "fontFamily": null,
            "fontsize": null,
            "color": "#0f0",
            "video_id": null,
            "creationDateTime": "2019-04-08T13:59:51Z"
        }

Answer (score 1):

You would need to do it like this:

```
fetch("/api/barrages", { method: 'GET' })
    .then(function (res) {
        return res.json()
    }
    .then(function(myJson){
         console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson))
     })
   })
```